# VBA array allowed data types

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays#:%7E:text=You%20can%20declare%20an%20array,of%20the%20same%20data%20type.&text=By%20default%2C%20an%20array%20is,is%20364%20rather%20than%20365.) says that

> "You can declare an array to work with a set of values of the same
> data type."

Does that mean that I can, in fact, declare the array as `Variant` data type, so in the end I can use the array with multiple types of data?

```
Dim arr(1 to 3)
arr(1) = "stackoverflow" 'string
arr(2) = 1,000,000.00 'number
arr(3) = dateserial(2020,07,28)
```

Is that ok? Or it is bad practice?

Comment: Hello, BigBen, thanks for the attention. I want to get a spreadsheet range data to array (arr = myrange.Value), handle the data and then paste it back to the spreadsheet (cells(1,1).Resize(UBound(arr,1),UBound(arr,2)).Value = arr). The problem is that the data consists of columns of strings, numbers and dates. Is thak ok? Or should I create an array for each column, so I could declare its data type explicitly?

Comment: It's fine to read the range into a single array.

Comment: In that case, proceed exactly as you have set out. That's a textbook case for a Variant array.